# Relation chain_config fields and tx_cpu_usage

Tags: unit-tests

In **chain_config.hpp** I need a new field "alfa_opt".

```
struct chain_config {
...
   uint32_t   max_block_cpu_usage;                 ///< the maxiumum billable cpu usage (in microseconds) for a block
   uint32_t   alfa_opt; /// < my parameter
...
```

But when I add it to "FC_REFLECT" item:

```
FC_REFLECT(eosio::chain::chain_config,                                                         
           (max_block_net_usage)(target_block_net_usage_pct)                                   
           (max_transaction_net_usage)(base_per_transaction_net_usage)(net_usage_leeway)       
           (context_free_discount_net_usage_num)(context_free_discount_net_usage_den)          

           (max_block_cpu_usage)(target_block_cpu_usage_pct)                                   
           (max_transaction_cpu_usage)(min_transaction_cpu_usage)                              

           (max_transaction_lifetime)(deferred_trx_expiration_window)(max_transaction_delay)   
           (max_inline_action_size)(max_inline_action_depth)(max_authority_depth)              
           (alfa_opt) // <=== that one (1)                                                        
)
```

Then unit tests

```
unittests/unit_test -t eosio_system_tests/setparams -- --wabt
```

failed with

```
"3080004 tx_cpu_usage_exceeded: Transaction exceeded the current CPU usage limit imposed on the transaction"
```

When I comment line (1), then test will be passed.

1) Why is that relation between field and tx_cpu_usage exists?

2) What is true-way to add a new field to chain_config?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is relation between fields and eos resources because by adding that field to your code it will take more ram,cpu and bandwith to process.,To resolve this issue stake more resources than current staked resources.

Comment: Thank you. But this is a chain config. How can I stake more resources for system itself? As I can see in **controller.cpp** (controller_impl) no resources acquired for that struct (chain_config). Can you tell me where to find that operation?

Comment: If you are on local net then you need to deploy system contract to stack resources for that follow 9 steps from " https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence "but if you are on mainnet/testnet then follow these commands as shown in https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-delegatebw